# Multiple linear regression and ANOVA in R

Tags: r

So, I have a table which consists of 20 football teams and 6 variables, the variables are     X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 and X6.

```
X1 = % of goals shots at goal which result in a goal

X2 = goals scored outside the box

X3 = ratio of short to long passes

X4 = Number of ball crosses

X5 = Average number of goals conceded

X6 = # Yellow cards recieved
```

and then I have a Y column which is the number of league points each team has.
How would I perform multiple linear regression and ANOVA on this? I am at a complete loss with  R.

Thanks

The data is this:

Comment: I've no idea (and cant find a way on the link provided) to copy paste a microsoft excel document as a table in the OP.
Does this help at all?
http://puu.sh/szOW3/7679449088.png

Comment: save your file as csv, then load it in R using `mydata = read.csv("filename.csv", row.names = 1, header = TRUE)`. After that, copy the output of `dput(mydata)` and paste it in your question to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple Linear Regression

The `lm()` in base R does exactly what you want (no need to use `glm` if you are only running linear regression):

```
Reg = lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, data = mydata)
```

If Y and the X's are the only columns in your data.frame, you can use this much simpler syntax:

```
Reg = lm(Y ~ ., data = mydata)
```

The `.` means "all other columns".

To see regression output (as suggested by @Manassa Mauler):

```
summary(Reg)
```

Refer to `?lm` and `?glm` for more information.

#### ANOVA

If you want to compare nested models with the "intercept-only" model, you can do something like the following:

```
fit0 = lm(Y ~ 1, data = mydata)
fit1 = update(fit0, . ~ . + X1)
fit2 = update(fit1, . ~ . + X2)
fit3 = update(fit2, . ~ . + X3)
fit4 = update(fit3, . ~ . + X4)
fit5 = update(fit4, . ~ . + X5)
fit6 = update(fit5, . ~ . + X6)
```

This successively adds an additional variable to the intercept-only model.

To compare them, use the `anova()` function:

```
anova(fit0, fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5, fit6, test = "F")
```

Refer to `?anova` or `?anova.lm` for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Just set up the multiple regression as follows using the `glm` function and then extract the results using `summary`.

```
model <- glm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6)
summary(model)
```

Comment: Hi Manassa. Thanks for this, however I'm still confused



When I type this into a script I get this:
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Y' not found"

Comment: @Steven have you loaded in the data correctly? Can you provide the R code you're using so I can see why you're getting that error.

Comment: Hi @Manassa Mauler. Thank you for the help so far, I am really kicking myself about this I just cannot wrap my head around it. I also cannot seem to format this comment. http://puu.sh/szZZL/ae8d2bb1ee.png

Thanks.

Comment: @Steven so it looks like you need to access the column in the object called mydata. You have to use `$` notation to do this. In my code it would look like `glm(mydata$Y~mydata$X1+mydata$X2)` Also, make sure your mydata object looks correct by using `head(mydata)`

Comment: @ManassaMauler or more conveniently `glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = mydata)`.

Comment: The suggested solution will not work unless `Y` and `X`s are not variables. If they are columns of a data.frame, you will need to specify a `data` argument as suggested by @useR.